# How can I Change Scroll sensitivity of MX Master 2s's scroll wheel?

Tags: mouse, logitech

I've been using [Logitech MX master 2s](https://www.logitech.com/en-in/product/mx-master-2s-flow) with Ubuntu 18.04 for like a week now and this mouse comes with 2 settings for scrolling one is a click to click scroll like a normal mouse and other is a hyperfast free scroll. if you scroll fast enough the click to click scroll turns to hyper-fast scrolling, which is a really good feature on Windows or Mac you can control the sensitivity of when Click to Click scrolling gets converted to hyperfast free scrolling. I think this is also possible in Ubuntu (or lets say Linux) because it's been demoed on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_MX_Master).

on Arch Wiki it's written and I quote:

[image: Arch Wiki Text]

But Solaar on Ubuntu doesn't have that slider

[image: Solaar on Ubuntu]

also, note that Solaar hasn't been updated since 2014-04-20. do you have any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: How did you install Solaar in Ubuntu?

Comment: You could try out the unofficial driver for logitech mice and keyboard and change the setting for the smartshift threshold in config. The installation and a sample config is here:https://askubuntu.com/a/1246278/678626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first uninstall your current solaar version, then try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/pwr/Solaar.git
cd Solaar
```

**Update: The following is unnecessary now, as the pull request has been merged:**

---

> unfortunately the support for the MX Master 2s seems not to be in there yet, but there's a pull request with the support, so you could do:
>       git pull origin pull/399/head
>
> to download it into your local repository. If it opens an editor just hit save and exit it.
>
> ---

**Continue here**

Then you can run

```
sudo python setup.py install
/usr/local/bin/solaar
```

[image: Solaar]

Comment: The pull request has been merged, there is no more need to pull it.

Comment: The version from the official Ubuntu 18.04 packet repositories does not yet contain the patch. Installing it from the Git repository is necessary but works without a problem.

Comment: I have the MX Master 2S and after I followed the above instructions, I don't get the other options/info at Solarr except for: Battery, Wireless Link...

Comment: I made a mess out of my Ubuntu 20.04. Firstly, I installed python (```apt install python```) and got Python 2. Then installed Python 3. Then the package pyudev (```pip3 install pyudev```) and tried some tweaks to the scripts. 
But, I couldn't pass this error: ```Solaar: missing required system package python3-pyudev```.
Luckily, the answer from @Alonzzo2 worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to config the smart-shift for **MX MASTER 2S** (which can't be configured via the UI), Follow [Catscrash's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1059638/527764), then go to Solaar's CLI instead of the GUI, and run the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/sudo solaar config 1 smart-shift 30
```

- `1` is your device number (run `solaar show` to see a device list.)
- `30` is a number between 0-50 (0 is total free scroll).