# Logitech MX Master 2s cursor speed very slow on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 19.04, logitech

after updating my Ubuntu to 19.04 the cursor speed is very slow.
I have a Logitech MX Master 2S connected by bluetooth.

With the previous version of Ubuntu the speed was ok. Obviously I have already increased the mouse speed to maximum in the devices settings panel.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can try `xinput` way : https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity

Comment: xinput does nothing to this badass mouse. Thanks for answering.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted @fabio-sasso

Comment: This is possibly duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149310/logitech-mx-master-2s-via-bluetooth-change-pointer-speed/1246278
View the answer there for an unofficial driver of logitech mice and keyboard for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution :**

We are going to change a value in a file.  Change the value `128` in the flowing file to `200` (temporary), or what ever value suits you.

```
sudo nano /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity
```

Once you found values you are comfortable with, make the change permanent using an Upstart job:

Now: **Create a new udev rule :**

Now we need to apply the settings during the system start. Therefore, press Alt + F2, type

`gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/trackpoint.rules`

and hit Enter (this will ask you for your password). Then paste the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="serio", DRIVERS=="psmouse", DEVPATH=="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2", ATTR{sensitivity}="220", ATTR{speed}="110"
```

Save the file and either reboot or run the commands above:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

sudo udevadm trigger
```

**2nd solution :**

you can also type in terminal (my prefered solution) :

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev && sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-libinput && sudo reboot`