# Logitech Options on Linux

Tags: logitech

I am a new ubuntu user and want to use my machine to it's full extent, so I looked for Logitech Options software for my Logitech MX Master 2s on linux, but found nothing.

Will the software run through Wine? If not, is there any other way to install Logitech Options or get to customize the functions of macro buttons and the thumb wheel?

Comment: The Flow feature looks good. We need that.

Comment: If you're looking for pairing, and some general options configuration, install `Solaar`. Don't bother with WINE IMHO.

Answer (score 93):

I was having the same problem as you did/do. The solution that I found to address this issue was installing Solaar.

This application allows you to manage Logitech devices. I have a Logitech 400 plus (A keyboard with a mouse) and with that, I can achieve the things that I needed to change.

```
sudo apt install solaar
solaar
```

And you're going to see on the top right corner a battery icon indicating the battery remaining on your device. Hope this helps you!

Comment: This only gives battery information in the status for these mice, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat Can you explain as it appears [to do much more](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar)

Comment: This worked great for me. Experienced no issues like what @MuhammadbinYusrat said.

Comment: For me `solaar` would just hang on startup, until I rebooted

Comment: Add this (`solaar`) to your Startup Applications GUI to make it run after every reboot.

Comment: MX Master 3 here and Solaar is working great! Thanks mate!

Comment: My MX keys mini works at Ubuntu 20.04. I needed to reboot the machine, after installation, to software to be able to write at ´udev´
I followed the installation guide on the Github repo, there is used pip of python to install

Comment: I needed to install a newer version as my OS (Ubuntu 20.04) only installed version 1.0.1 by default. This is known potential issue as pointed out on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar#readme). The older version did not find my MX Master 3S, but the new one (1.1.4) did it perfectly!

Answer (score 14):

There is an unofficial driver **[logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops)** for Logitech mice and keyboards which works for me with Ubuntu 18.04 and Manjaro and the MX Master 2S and 3S.

Features include but not limited to:

- thumb button with gestures,
- smartshift scrolling with an individual threshold
- individual dpi settings.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246278/678626) on how to install and configure the driver.

The Flow feature is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops/issues/23) but there seems to exist an alternative for Windows/Linux/Mac called [barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier).

Comment: Been trying to use Flow with my k850/m720 kit even with Windows/Mac it was hit & miss. Barrier is awesome and now using it with Deepin and Win10. Thanks!

Comment: Barrier worked like a charm

Comment: Barrier is awesome until you need national characters like ó ł ę etc. Because it is unable to properly send the altGr+? combination. There are hacks but it is not perfect.

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo apt install solaar
solaar
```

This was the answer for me. I used it to enable a unifying USB receiver, and share it with an ERGO K860 keyboard and an MX ERGO trackball. [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) will detect all devices paired with supported Unifying, Lightspeed, or Nano receivers, and at the very least display some basic information about them. A really excellent utility. Props to @vito genovese for the heads-up.

Comment: I installed using this guide, but the version was old.  
Install solaar by using this official solaar [guide](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation) to get the latest version

Answer (score 9):

As it stands Logitech Options is not available for Linux and it does not appear to be running in WINE. You could always check the WINE website for more information, [but it looks like there is nothing yet](https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/search?name=Logitech).

You should always checkout the Arch Linux Wiki for help. [Here is the article covering the MX Master.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_MX_Master)

[Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/) might be what you are looking for.

From the Github page:

```
Piper is a GTK+ application to configure gaming mice. 
Piper is merely a graphical frontend to the ratbagd DBus daemon, see the libratbag
README for instructions on how to run ratbagd
```

Answer (score 5):

After trying many other solutions listed here, [logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops) has worked great so far: custom button-mapping, gesture support, smart shift, etc. Nearly every LogiOptions feature seems to be supported by it. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and using an [MX Master 3](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/mx-master-3.910-005692.html).

Folks may be put off by it because there's no GUI, and build and installation aren't trivial (I had a problem where [cmake couldn't find libevdev](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops/issues/142#issuecomment-1036430282)). That being said, Danish Shakeel's [Configure Logitech MX Master 3 on Linux](https://danishshakeel.me/configure-logitech-mx-master-3-on-linux-logiops/) blog post helped quite a bit, especially for getting started with the configuration file. The [documentation for the configuration file](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops/wiki/Configuration) is quite good, but it can get a little tricky and there aren't many examples out there aside from [the example in the repository](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops/blob/master/logid.example.cfg).

For what it's worth, here's my configuration (located at **/etc/logid.cfg** by default):

```
devices: (
    {
        name: "Wireless Mouse MX Master 3";
        smartshift:
        {
            on: true;
            threshold: 30;
            default_threshold: 30;
        };
        hiresscroll:
        {
            hires: true;
            invert: true;
            target: false;
        };
        dpi: 1700;
        buttons: (
            {
                cid: 0x52; // scroll wheel button
                action =
                {
                    type: "Keypress";
                    keys: [ "KEY_RIGHTMETA" ]; // open activities overview
                }    
            },
            {
                cid: 0x53; // back button
                action =
                {
                    type: "Keypress";
                    keys: [ "KEY_RIGHTMETA", "KEY_PAGEDOWN" ]; // move to previous space
                }    
            },
            {
                cid: 0x56; // forward button
                action =
                {
                    type: "Keypress";
                    keys: [ "KEY_RIGHTMETA", "KEY_PAGEUP" ]; // move to next space
                }    
            },
            {
                cid: 0xc4; // mode shift button
                action =
                {
                    type: "Keypress";
                    keys: [ "KEY_RIGHTMETA", "KEY_A" ]; // show applications
                }    
            }
        );
    }
);
```

For mapping keyboard shortcuts, refer to **/usr/include/linux/input.h**.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for ways to configure my G700s on linux. `piper` works very well for configuring my mouse and apparently works for a number of other gaming mice.

edit: I got `piper` from the official arch repository, but is available in and the ubuntu repository.

Comment: you might mention that `piper` is available from the ubuntu software center in your answer or how else it can be obtained.

Comment: +1 Ubuntu 20.04 - Works great with my Logitech G502 for programming the buttons with keyboard macros to switch spaces.

Comment: Piper worked very well for logitech mouse.

Answer (score 2):

**logiops** might be a good choice, this is an unofficial driver for Logitech mice and keyboard.

[project page](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops)

Answer (score 2):

I tried Solaar and piper they both didnt work at all , then I tried something called "easystroke gesture recognition" basically its Logitech options on steroids , you have much more options and you can custom everything and it can be used on any mice.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Solaar as suggested by [@vito-genovese](https://askubuntu.com/users/1173398/vito-genovese) solved the connectivty issue that support said that Logitech Options would help. Unfortunatly, it is not possible to reconfig keys or change speed profiles with the app, but helped with connecting my Logitech MX Vertical correctly with Ubuntu.

While trying to open the app I got the following error:

```bash
Solaar: missing required package 'python-pyudev'
```

I solved it installing `python3-pyudev` based on [this issue report](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/issues/438):

```bash
sudo apt install python3-pyudev
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to change my Logi K650 so that I didn't have to press `fn` key in order to use F-keys (as in `F1...F2` keys).

The package `solaar` works great, I just had to unplug and plug back in the dongle after running the program for the first time, then wait about a minute for the UI to show available options, and finally turn off the `Swap Fx function` toggle button (had to press the lock icon twice to unlock the option):

[image: image depicting Solaar window with Logi K650 keyboard options displayed and an arrow pointing to the Swap Fx function option which is turned off]

Answer (score -1):

About unifying remotes, you might also wanna look at ltunify if you just need to pair. Easy use. But it's just for pairing.

Comment: The unifying remote for Logitech needs no software what so ever. It is a hardware level device that works even during boot to select in GRUB.

Comment: ltunify is software though. Gonna link Gentoo wiki as I hope link won't die too  fast, but sure it's in ubuntu repo as well https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ltunify. Seen for SuSE too (remember you can buy unpaired unifying dongle - you need to pair once)

Comment: Does not change my comment no software needed for the keyboard to connect to the receiver.

Comment: I originally downvoted this answer as it's mostly unrelated to the original question, and my keyboard always worked when plugging in the receiver. However, today I faced a scenario where it wouldn't and `ltunify` helped me out. Still mostly out of scope, but still useful in the topic of Logitech devices. Sadly, I can only unvote it if it gets edited lol